# Validar Expressão Regular em String - Java

Tags: java, regex

Olá, gostaria de validar uma String no java recebida de um INPUT.
Essa validação seria para determinar se o usuário realmente digitou um email válido no seguinte padrão:

"**XXXXXXXX**@**YYYYYY**.com" ou "**XXXXXXXX**@**YYYYYY**.com.br"

Onde [XXX..] e [YYY...] seja caracteres válidos e a quantidade total de caracteres da String não ultrapassem 50.

No meu caso quando chegar no contexto JAVA já terei a String preenchida com o que o usuário digitou.

Comment: Regex para validar email é [mais complicado do que parece](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html). Há [regras demais](https://emailregex.com/email-validation-summary/) e quanto [mais precisa é a regex, mais complicada ela fica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373724) (e quanto mais simples, maior a chance de falsos positivos)